# Can we get the exact solution of large-scale quadratic programming problems (quadratic objective, linear inequality constraints) using KKT condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, constrained-optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-programming

<sub>[Crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/443636) at MathOverflow</sub>

---

Consider a quadratic programming problem with the following format:
$$
\text{min} Q(x) = c^Tx+\frac{1}{2}x^TDx \\
$$
$$
\text{s.t.} Ax\leq b, \\
x\geq 0
$$
where $D$ is a $n\times n$ positive definite matrix and $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix. We know when $n$ and $m$ are small, for example, when both of them are 2, we can solve the problem and get the exact solution using the KKT condition. However, when $n$ and $m$ are large (meaning that we have a large-scale quadratic programming problem. I think we are also able to get the exact solution using the KKT condition.

However, to the best of my knowledge, I cannot find any reference for this. The book '[quadratic programming](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=3b56ceb8bc62ccf82e4d80cbcf58b5c4f307a51e)' said that this type of question can be solved in polynomial time (page 3), for example, the interior point method. But as far as I know, the interior point method only can get the near-optimal solution making the objective function within the acceptable tolerance (like $10^{-7}$).
We can also refer to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92939/can-all-convex-optimization-problems-be-solved-in-polynomial-time-using-interior) about using the interior point method to solve the quadratic programming method.

My question: is it possible for us to get the exact solution to the aforementioned question when $n$ and $m$ are large? How expensive it is if we want to get the exact solution (global optimum) of the quadratic programming problem I mentioned before? And how it relates to the number of $m$? Is it impossible to calculate it even with computers? I will really appreciate it if you can offer some references for this problem.
I also posted [a question in "mathoverflow"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443636/can-we-get-the-exact-solution-of-large-scale-quadratic-programming-problems-qua), but it seems that there are no answers there, and I received a suggestion to post my question here.

Comment: It might come up to what your mental idea of "computing the exact solution" is. Can you compute exactly $\sqrt{2}$ of a computer? What does it mean? Is that concept of 'computing' different from what an interior-point method does, ultimately?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thank you for your comment. For example, if you have a small-scale convex optimization problem with a quadratic objective and linear inequality constraints, like this [link](http://www.universalteacherpublications.com/univ/ebooks/or/Ch15/examp1.htm), you are supposed to get the solution that is exactly the optimal. I think for large-scale convex optimization problems with a quadratic objective and linear inequality constraints, it should be the same. I wonder whether it is possible to get some 'exact solution' like this for large-scale problems.

Comment: @ximengfan What Federico Polini is saying is that "computing" almost always implies using floating point approximations, and so you cannot "compute" the "exact" solution anyway. All you can do is compute things to floating point accuracy. So if you're already approximating, using an interior point method does not seem like an additional imposition.

Comment: A key problem here is that you have to determine which constraints are active in order to apply the KKT conditions.  Conventionally, this is done using an "active set method"  If an interior point method is used can try to determine tthe active constraints and solve the KKT conditions by rounding off near 0 values to 0.

Comment: @BrianBorchers As far as I know, the active set method can be regarded as a simplex method for non-linear programming. The iteration complexity for the active method is $2^m$. I don't know whether this is the reason why people prefer to use interior point methods for large-scale convex quadratic programming problems? And I do not fully understand " solve the KKT conditions by rounding off near 0 values to 0", I will really appreciate it if you can explain more about it.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you for the explanation. As far as I know, the interior point method is an iterative method to get a 'near-optimal solution'. Iterations will terminate when the difference between two iterations is smaller than the set tolerance. I don't know whether my understanding of your comment is correct: this tolerance may not be caused by the optimization but by using floating point approximations? But from the book '[convex optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)', even calculating the optimization problem manually, we still have such 'tolerance'.

Comment: @ximengfan There are two sources of error for interior point methods: The fact that you have a tolerance at which you stop, and the fact that you cannot solve *any* problem exactly but only in floating point approximation.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you again! What if I use the kKT condition and manually solve the problem? In that case, is it possible to get the exact solution? I think it is possible, kike this [post](http://www.universalteacherpublications.com/univ/ebooks/or/Ch15/examp1.htm). And in our course exercises, we were asked to do so. Also,, is this the only way that is possible to get the exact solution?

Comment: @ximengfan Perhaps. I'm not sure. It is possible that you can find the exact solution, at least in principle, if all entries in your matrix and in the constraint vector are rational numbers. In that case it seems plausible to me that the solution is expressible only in terms of square roots. But for comparison, you should consider the case of solving quintic equations. You cannot solve these exactly because you cannot express the solution as a formula.

Comment: If you can determine the active set of constraints, then solving the KKT conditions for that active set is simply solving a linear system of equations, which could in theory be done in exact rational arithmetic (but not practical for a problem of any size.)  If you have a floating point solution, you could try to determine the active set of constraints from that approximate solution by rounding.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I kind of get your point. Thank you so much! May I have one follow-up question? If this is the case, why do people (current literature when formulating a real-life problem as an operation research problem) like to make the optimization problem convex and lead to a unique global optimal solution? Because it seems that people can rarely get that global optimal solution.

Comment: @ximengfan For a taste of numerical optimization with arbitrary-precision rationals, take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2086542/339790)

Comment: Primal-dual interior point methods for conic LP with tractable cones can be very robust, accurate, and efficient in practice.  The solutions obtained by these methods are normally perfectly adequate for applications.

Comment: @ximengfan I believe one reason you're confused is that in text books, the solution of simple examples can always be computed quite easily as integers or at least as simple fractions. But that's for *illustrative* purposes. "Real" problems do not have this structure: If a rational solution exists, then it is likely going to be a very complicated fraction. In practice, of course, the entries of matrices and vectors are only known to measurement accuracy and then represented as floating point values, and so the solution will in general also only be known to floating point accuracy.

Comment: @WolfgangBangertho Yes, this is what makes me confused. Thank you so much for your explanation.